# How to use CROSS JOIN and CROSS APPLY in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to Spark and Scala, I writing Spark SQL code. I am in situation to apply CROSS JOIN and CROSS APPLY in my logic. Here I will post the SQL query which I have to convert to spark SQL.

```
select Table1.Column1,Table2.Column2,Table3.Column3
from Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2 CROSS APPLY Table3
```

I need the above query to convert in to SQLContext in Spark SQL. Kindly help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 11):

First set the below property in spark conf

```
spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true
```

then `dataFrame1.join(dataFrame2)` will do Cross/Cartesian join,

we can use below query also for doing the same

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from table1 CROSS JOIN table2 CROSS JOIN table3...")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It clarifies the cross join totally. Can you add any good practice and/or example to carry on a CROSS APPLY. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Set Spark Configuration ,

```
var sparkConf: SparkConf = null

 sparkConf = new SparkConf()

.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
```

Explicit Cross Join in spark 2.x using crossJoin Method

**crossJoin(right: Dataset[_]): DataFrame**

```
var df_new = df1.crossJoin(df2);
```

Note : Cross joins are one of the most time consuming joins and often should be avoided.

Comment: The crossJoin is quite handy and does not need the spark.sql.crossjoin setting.