# cross apply equivalent in apache sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below SQL server query to validate sql records and display inappropriate record

```
    select t.*, x.*
    from sallutest t
    cross apply (values
    (1, case when t.age = 25 then 'Age is 25' end),
    (2, case when t.age > 29 then 'Age is not in 20s' end),
    (3, case when t.department <> 'IT' then 'Dept not IT' end)
    ) x(FailedValidationId, FailedValidation)
    where x.FailedValidation is not null
```

However this query fails in Apache SQL.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you enable it in spark ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763682/how-to-use-cross-join-and-cross-apply-in-spark-sql

Comment: I just checked the config. It's not enabled.

Comment: If you enable it should work ;)

Comment: After enabling, it shows "missing 'JOIN' at 'apply" error

Comment: Cross apply seems to be unavailable in spark sql