# Pyspark joining dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to join two Dataframes, but my goal is to repeat all rows from the second DF for each id of the first DF.

For example:

First DF:

| id | user | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H234 | 3 |
| 2 | H123 | 4 |

Second DF:

| id | trait | conditional_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blood Pressure | 2 |
| 2 | Stroke | 4 |
| 3 | Joint Pain | 3 |

Output DF:

| id | user | condition | trait | conditional_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H234 | 3 | Blood Pressure | 3 |
| 1 | H234 | 3 | Stroke | 7 |
| 1 | H234 | 3 | Joint Pain | 6 |
| 2 | H123 | 4 | Blood Pressure | 4 |
| 2 | H123 | 4 | Stroke | 8 |
| 2 | H123 | 4 | Joint Pain | 4 |

So, the mean idea is to add all the from the second DataFrame to the first, and sum the columns `condition` and `conditional_score` if the `condition` is equal or lesser than the `conditional_score`.

I'm new to PySpark and I don't know how to proceed, could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this using a cross join.

You should ensure that you have the [`spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true` configuration property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763682/how-to-use-cross-join-and-cross-apply-in-spark-sql) set to true.

#### Approach 1: Using Spark SQL

You may then achieve this using spark sql by

1. Creating temporary views for each dataframe

```py
first_df.createOrReplaceTempView("first_df")
second_df.createOrReplaceTempView("second_df")
```

2. Running the following sql on your spark session

```py
output_df = spark_session.sql("""
    SELECT
        first_df.id,
        first_df.user,
        first_df.score as condition,
        second_df.trait,
        CASE
            WHEN first_df.score <= second_df.conditional_score THEN first_df.score + second_df.conditional_score
            ELSE first_df.score 
        END as conditional_score
    FROM
        first_df
    CROSS JOIN
        second_df
""")
```

#### Approach 2: Using Pyspark API

You may also achieve this using the pyspark api

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df = first_df.alias("first_df")\
                    .crossJoin(second_df.alias("second_df"))\
                    .select(
                        F.col('first_df.id'),
                        F.col('first_df.user'),
                        F.col('first_df.score').alias('condition'),
                        F.col('second_df.trait'),
                        F.when( 
 F.col('first_df.score') <= F.col('second_df.conditional_score'), F.col('first_df.score') +F.col('second_df.conditional_score')
).otherwise( F.col('first_df.score') ).alias("conditional_score")
                    )
```

Let me know if this works for you.