# CROSS APPLY alternative in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am migrating a SQL stored procedure from SQL server to Spark SQL. One of the statement in SP uses CROSS APPLY but spark doesn't have CROSS APPLY. I researched and found that INNER JOIN can be used to replace the CROSS APPLY. Below is the SQL server code:

```
SELECT
 H.BillingDocument
,H.BillingDocumentItem
,H.BillingDate
 ,H.Soldto
,H.SalesOrganization
,H.SalesDocument
,M.MaterialPricingGroup
,MaterialPricingGroupText as mpg_description
--,COUNT(*) as item_count
,H.BillingQuantity
,X.AttachPrimaryCategory
-- SELECT * FROM 
INTO
    #TEMP_FO_ATTACH
FROM sales.dbo.bi__billing_documents H

INNER JOIN masterdata.dbo.bi_materials M ON M.material = H.material and M.SalesOrganization = H.SalesOrganization
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 X.AttachPrimaryCategory
    FROM -- SELECT * FROM
        marketing.dbo.attach_secondary_cat X 
INNER JOIN #TEMP_PrimaryForFO P ON 
        P.MaterialPricingGroup <> M.MaterialPricingGroup 
        AND P.PrimaryCategory = X.AttachPrimaryCategory
        AND P.BillingDate between H.BillingDate and H.BillingDate + @FollowOnDays 
        and P.Soldto = H.Soldto and P.SalesOrganization = H.SalesOrganization
    WHERE  X.ValidAttachmentMPG = M.MaterialPricingGroup
    ORDER BY P.BillingDate, P.PrimaryCategory
        ) X

WHERE 
    (LEFT(RIGHT(H.Plant,2),1) not in ('6','8') or H.Plant between '660' and '689') and H.billingtype in ('ZF2','ZD2')
    AND H.BillingDate between @RunFromDate and @AttachEnd
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #TEMP_POS_ATTACH Z WHERE Z.BillingDocumentItem = H.BillingDocumentItem and Z.BillingDocument = H.BillingDocument)
```

I tried rewriting the same in spark and below is my code, but the results are not matching between SQL server and Spark even though all the tables and temp views are having same data in both.

Spark Code:

```
fo_attach_df = spark.sql("""

SELECT DISTINCT
     H.BillingDocument
    ,H.BillingDocumentItem
    ,H.BillingDate
     ,H.Soldto
    ,H.SalesOrganization
    ,H.SalesDocument
    ,M.MaterialPricingGroup
    ,M.MaterialPricingGroupText as mpg_description
    ,H.BillingQuantity
    ,X.AttachPrimaryCategory

FROM sales.bi__billing_documents H
INNER JOIN masterdata.bi__materials M ON M.material = H.material and M.SalesOrganization = H.SalesOrganization
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT * FROM(
              SELECT DISTINCT X.AttachPrimaryCategory,
              X.ValidAttachmentMPG,
              P.SalesOrganization,
              p.SOLDTO,
              RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY p.SALESORGANIZATION ORDER BY P.BillingDate, P.PrimaryCategory) AS RNK
              FROM marketing.attach_secondary_cats X
                INNER JOIN primary_for_fo P ON 
                 P.PrimaryCategory = X.AttachPrimaryCategory
                INNER JOIN sales.bi__billing_documents H
                ON P.BillingDate between H.BillingDate and H.BillingDate + int({}) 
                and P.Soldto = H.Soldto and P.SalesOrganization = H.SalesOrganization
                INNER JOIN masterdata.bi__materials M
                on P.MaterialPricingGroup <> M.MaterialPricingGroup
                
                AND M.material = H.material and M.SalesOrganization = H.SalesOrganization
            )TMP
            WHERE RNK = 1
        ) X
        ON  X.SalesOrganization = h.SalesOrganization
        AND X.SOLDTO = H.SOLDTO
        AND X.ValidAttachmentMPG = M.MaterialPricingGroup
        LEFT JOIN POS_ATTACH Z 
        ON Z.BillingDocumentItem = H.BillingDocumentItem 
        and Z.BillingDocument = H.BillingDocument
        WHERE 
            (LEFT(RIGHT(H.Plant,2),1) not in ('6','8') or H.Plant between '660' and '689') and H.billingtype in ('ZF2','ZD2')
            AND H.BillingDate between  CAST('{}' AS DATE) and   CAST('{}' AS DATE)
            AND z.BILLINGDOCUMENT IS NULL AND Z.BillingDocumentItem IS NULL

""".format(FollowOnDays, RunFromDate, attach_end))
```

I spent 3-4 hours to figure out how to correct my code. Please help what is wrong with my code and if possible please help with the equivalent code. Appreciate any help.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763682/how-to-use-cross-join-and-cross-apply-in-spark-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763682/how-to-use-cross-join-and-cross-apply-in-spark-sql)

Comment: @Stu I already tried using the same solution but I am having hard time rewriting this.