# How to use string_split() with delimiter in databricks?

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to use string_split() function in databricks to convert below dataframe.

Source dataframe stored as TempView in Databricks:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value-1,value-2,value-3 |
| 2 | value-1,value-4 |

Output needed:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value-1 |
| 1 | value-2 |
| 1 | value-3 |
| 3 | value-1 |
| 3 | value-4 |

I tried below code:

```
%sql
SELECT ID, value
FROM TempView
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(value, ',')
GROUP BY cs.PERMID, value
```

but I am getting Parse exception.

Comment: can  you add the complete error messsage in text form

Comment: also the is ni CRPSS APPLY you need to use LEFT OUTER Join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763682/how-to-use-cross-join-and-cross-apply-in-spark-sql or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdC65Rge3yc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `string_split` function in Databricks SQL. But there is `split` function for that ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/split.html)).

Also in your case it's easier to write code using the combination of `split` and `explode` ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/explode.html)) functions. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT ID, explode(split(value, ',')) FROM TempView
```

Comment: It works and I would like to suggest this:
```df = spark.sql ("""SELECT ID, explode(split(value, ',')) FROM TempView""").dropDuplicates()```