# missing 'JOIN' at 'apply'(line 1, pos 109)

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I'm trying to use `STRING_SPLIT` function in my `Azure 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)` to separate comma separated value So I wrote following SQL code
`%sql`

```
select EmpPhoneNo, Split.value  
from EmpPhone as Emp 
Cross apply STRING_SPLIT(EmpPhoneNo,',') as Split
```

I got error message saying

`ParseException:  missing 'JOIN' at 'apply'(line 1, pos 116)`

Can you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi - please tag your question with the actual DBMS you are using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc) as this syntax is likely to be DBMS-specific

Comment: Is this Databricks that you are using? If so [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284824/2221001).